# How can I automatically post to a Google+ fan page from an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, google-plus-pages

On Facebook I can use apps to import an RSS feed and automatically post to my Facebook fan page. I haven't found anything similar on Google+

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
http://hootsuite.com

or 
http://dlvr.it - only at Pro or Ultimate Plan

Answer (score 0):

There's probablly an [ifttt](http://ifttt.com/dashboard) recipe for that ... although my Google-fu failed to find it.

Comment: Maybe this? https://plus.google.com/117764940156284555195/posts/Eiqhf8RRuAV

Comment: thanks. Any way of doing this without SMS?

Comment: [The Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) Is still readonly, so unless someone has written a module to exploit some other method of posting updates (eg: a vanilla HTTP session) it likely isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that for Google+. Twitter and Facebook allow you to post via RSS.